# SQL Server slow select from large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, events

I have a table with about 20+ million records.

Structure is like:

```
EventId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
SourceUserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DestinationUserId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
CreatedAt DATETIME
TypeId INT
MetaId INT
```

Table is receiving about 100k+ records each day.

I have indexes on each column except MetaId, as it is not used in 'where' clauses

The problem is when i want to pick up eg. latest 100 records for desired SourceUserId

Query sometimes takes up to 4 minutes to execute, which is not acceptable.

Eg.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE SourceUserId = '15b534b17-5a5a-415a-9fc0-7565199c3461'
AND 
(
 TypeId IN (2, 3, 4)
    OR 
 (TypeId = 60 AND SrcMemberId != DstMemberId)
)
ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC
```

I can't do partitioning etc as I am using Standard version of SQL Server and Enterprise is too expensive.

I also think that the table is quite small to be that slow.

I think the problem is with ORDER BY clause as db must go through much bigger set of data.

Any ideas how to make it quicker ?

Perhaps relational database is not a good idea for that kind of data.

Data is always being picked up ordered by CreatedAt DESC

Thank you for reading.

PabloX

Comment: Voting this one up, as I have almost exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll likely want to create a composite index for this type of query - when the query runs slowly it is most likely choosing to scan down an index on the CreatedAt column and perform a residual filter on the SourceUserId value, when in reality what you want to happen is to jump directly to all records for a given SourceUserId ordered properly - to achieve this, you'll want to create a composite index primarily on SourceUserId (performing an equality check) and secondarily on CreateAt (to preserve the order within a given SourceUserId value). You may want to try adding the TypeId in as well, depending on the selectivity of this column.

So, the 2 that will most likely give the best repeatable performance (try them out and compare) would be:

1. Index on (SourceUserId, CreatedAt)
2. Index on (SourceUserId, TypeId, CreatedAt)

As always, there are also many other considerations to take into account with determining how/what/where to index, as Remus discusses in a separate answer one big consideration is covering the query vs. keeping lookups. Additionally you'll need to consider write volumes, [possible fragmentation impact (if any)](http://blogs.mssqltips.com/blogs/chadboyd/archive/tags/Fragmentation/default.aspx), singleton lookups vs. large sequential scans, etc., etc.

Comment: Yeap, as with soo many SQL questions, the answer is not some magic SELECT trick but good old fashion index design.

Comment: Clustering this index and having a striped disk would help as well.

Answer (score 6):

> I have indexes on each column except
>   MetaId

Non-covering indexes will likely hit the ['tipping point'](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Tipping-Point-Query-Answers.aspx) and the query would revert to a table scan. Just adding an index on every column because it is used in a where clause does not equate good index design. To take your query for example, a good 100% covering index would be:

```
INDEX ON (SourceUserId , CreatedAt) INCLUDE (TypeId, SrcMemberId, DstMemberId)
```

Following index is also usefull, altough it still going to cause lookups:

```
INDEX ON (SourceUserId , CreatedAt) INCLUDE (TypeId)
```

and finaly an index w/o any included column *may* help, but is just as likely will be ignored (depends on the column statistics and cardinality estimates):

```
INDEX ON (SourceUserId , CreatedAt)
```

But a separate index on SourceUSerId and one on CreatedAt is basically useless for your query.

See [Index Design Basics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179560.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the table has indexes built on GUID values, indicates a possible series of problems that would affect performance:

- **High index fragmentation:** since new GUIDs are generated randomly, the index cannot organize them in a sequential order and the nodes are spread unevenly.
- **High number of page splits:** the size of a GUID (16 bytes) causes many page splits in the index, since there's a greater chance than a new value wont't fit in the remaining space available in a page.
- **Slow value comparison:** comparing two GUIDs is a relatively slow operation because all 33 characters must be matched.

Here a couple of resources on how to investigate and resolve these problems:

- [How to Detect Index Fragmentation in SQL Server 2000 and 2005](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/detect_fragmentation_sql2000_sql2005_p1.aspx)
- [Reorganizing and Rebuilding Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx)
- [How Using GUIDs in SQL Server Affect Index Performance](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/guid_performance_p1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend getting the data in 2 sep var tables

```
INSERT INTO @Table1
SELECT * FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE SourceUserId = '15b534b17-5a5a-415a-9fc0-7565199c3461'
AND 
(
 TypeId IN (2, 3, 4)
)
INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT * FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE SourceUserId = '15b534b17-5a5a-415a-9fc0-7565199c3461'
AND 
(
 (TypeId = 60 AND SrcMemberId != DstMemberId)
)
```

then apply a unoin from the selects, ordered and top. Limit the data from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a UNION:

```
SELECT TOP 100 x.*
  FROM (SELECT a.*
          FROM EVENTS a
         WHERE a.typeid IN (2, 3, 4)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT b.*
          FROM EVENTS b
         WHERE b.typeid = 60 
           AND b.srcmemberid != b.dstmemberid) x
 WHERE x.sourceuserid = '15b534b17-5a5a-415a-9fc0-7565199c3461'
```

Answer (score 1):

We've realised a minor gain by moving to a BIGINT IDENTITY key for our event table; by using that as a clustered primary key, we can cheat and use that for date ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure CreatedAt is indexed properly

Comment: It would be nice to benchmark the query with and without the `Order By CreatedAt` clause!

Comment: An index solely on CreatedAt wouldn't likely help this type of query as well as a composite on the equality filter SourceUserId - an index solely on CreatedAt would simply allow the optimizer to scan backwards down a B-Tree doing a residual filter check on the SourceUserId until it found 100 with the specified value (if the SourceUserId is very selective, this would likely cause a fairly long scan). If you composite index on SourceUserId then CreatedAt, the optimizer can skip the scan, seek to the given SourceUserId and simply pull out the pre-ordered final 100.

Answer (score 0):

you could split the query in two with an UNION to avoid the OR (which can cause your index not to be used), something like

```
   SElect * FROM(
 SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE SourceUserId = '15b534b17-5a5a-415a-9fc0-7565199c3461'
AND TypeId IN (2, 3, 4)
UNION  SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE SourceUserId = '15b534b17-5a5a-415a-9fc0-7565199c3461' 
 AND TypeId = 60 AND SrcMemberId != DstMemberId
)
ORDER BY CreatedAt DESC
```

Also, check that the uniqueidentifier indexes are not CLUSTERED.

Answer (score 0):

If there are 100K records added each day, you should check your index fragmentation.
And rebuild or reorganize it accordingly.
More info :
[SQLauthority](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/22/sql-server-difference-between-index-rebuild-and-index-reorganize-explained-with-t-sql-script/)